# Django last visited urls list

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-middleware, django-context

I'm writing django-based forum, and i've decided it would be suitable for user to browse his last pages. Also, user tracking middleware can be a good aid for suggestions, and so on.

1. I think, the easiest way to do it is to use the `Django Middleware`, but i ran into a problem: how to get the title of the page being rendered? Override `process_template_response`? Can i get the `{% block title %}` there?
2. The second server-side way is to use a template tag, i think. In the easiest case, it should should look like `{% block title %}{% last_visited _("Page title") %}{% endblock %}`.
3. The third, stupid way: make an ajax script, that will push current user's opened page with title  into his session. So, this method will just avoid us getting the page title.

I think, the right way is to get the `title` block from a template context in middleware. How can i do it?

Thanks.

## UPDATE

Made the [gist](https://gist.github.com/night-crawler/6193730) with realisation of the second method using `templates` and `django.cache`. The simplest usage:

```
{% block title %}{% save_visited _("Profile setup") %}{% endblock %}
...
{% load_visited 'visited' %}
{% for title, uri, dt in visited %}
    <a href="{{ uri }}">{{ title }} {% trans "at" %} {{ dt }}</a><br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, i'm still looking for a method allows to get the page's `{% block title %}` in the middleware. Of course, i can use, i.e., `lxml` parser and get the `title` in the `process_response` method, but it is an ugly overkill.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do you just want to track the last forum thread they had open? In that case it's just a single view that you are interested in tracking - the forum detail page? Using that you can easily add the page to the users session

Comment: I want to make a reusable app, that provides an ability to user to watch his site history, so he can back again quickly. If it will be ajax-like, user can get back from another session (if app uses cache with user.id key), from another tab, and so on. It's not just "remebmer this topic".

Answer (score 0):

In your case i would use the second approach slightly modified:

```
{% last_visited  current_page_title  current_page_url  num %}
```

which would do two things:

1. Store the current title and url in a session variable (list of last visited pages)
2. Render the num last visited pages from the same session variable

Comment: 2. I want to make ajax-select dropdown somewhere. Also in your approach i need to use a template variable to store the title. I think, it should be better to make another templatetag to render last_visited pages. But, anyway, i don't like this method: it's not pluggable, it's not lazy.